# Jekyll instance inside parent Jekyll instance possible?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll site hosted @GitHub Pages that was built by someone else @ sitename.com

I have just finished building a separate Jekyll instance(my first shot with Jekyll) for the blog, which needs to be located @ sitename.com/blog

I'm wondering if there's a way to make this happen, like a parent/child theme scenario. Essentially, I'd like to have 1 instance of Jekyll live inside a sub directory of Jekyll using GitHub Pages. If there is a way, how would one go about making that happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First instance in `github.com/userName/userName.github.io` (with custom url `sitename.com`)

Second instance in `github.com/userName/blog` repository (in `gh-pages` branch). Will be reached at `sitename.com/blog`.

Cool !